# WSO2 ESB not accepting large json data

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using `WSO2 ESB` in my java application for integration.
When I send very large **json data**, it shows the **ERROR** below:

Here is the error which I receive in `ESB`,

```
ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 82129 in class file org/mozilla/javascript/gen/c330
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefiningClassLoader.defineClass(DefiningClassLoader.java:62)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.defineClass(Codegen.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.createScriptObject(Codegen.java:81)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2361)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileReader(Context.java:1310)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileReader(Context.java:1282)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1224)
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:172)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.processJSONPayload(ScriptMediator.java:322)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:294)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:239)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:207)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:160)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:30)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:197)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:378)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:266)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:363)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not sure what causes this error. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: When I searched for a solution, I found this link [link] (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4353) .

Comment: In the link [link] (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4353) , it is said to use nashorn engine instead of rhino engine. If so, how to configure it(Nashorn engine) in WSO2 ESB server. I am using WSO2 ESB Server version 5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when processing large JSON data volumes, the code length must be less than 65536 characters, since the Script mediator converts the payload into a Java object so, try reducing the size of JSON.